# python 3 single quotation escapes parameter marker

Tags: string, python-3.x, quotation-marks

hi I want to reproduce the sql command

```
SP_HELPTEXT SP_CIW_STEP1
```

in cursor.execute in pyodb, using ? as parameter marker .

```
import pyodbc

ch = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=xxx;DATABASE=yyy;Trusted_Connection=True')
cur = ch.cursor()


cur.execute("sp_helptext '?'", 'SP_CIW_STEP1')
```

yields error:

> ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1
>   parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

---

And (thanks @ryugie)

```
cur.execute("sp_helptext ?", "'SP_CIW_STEP1'")
```

also causes error:

> [SQL Server]The object ''SP_CIW_STEP1'' does not exist in database
>   'xxx' or is invalid for this operation

---

While

```
cur.execute("? 'SP_CIW_STEP1'", 'sp_helptext')
```

works, yielding

> ```
> Out[28]: <pyodbc.Cursor at 0x9c21db0>
> ```

So it seems the single quotation ruins the parameter marker. I tried putting \ and adding r in front of the string. Doesn't work. Any help's appreciated here. Thanks-

Comment: what happens if you try `cur.execute("sp_helptext ?", "'SP_CIW_STEP1'")`?

Comment: doesn't work. See added part in OP. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter markers shouldn't be quoted, and neither should parameter values.

```
cur.execute("sp_helptext ?", "SP_CIW_STEP1")
```

should work just fine.

Comment: oh nice! In fact the sql command `SP_HELPTEXT your_stored_proc` doesn't require quotation mark on the name of the stored procedure in the first place~